# Is there a way to add tags to tests using serenity and gradle?

Tags: gradle, serenity-bdd

Background: Moving the testing serenity framework to use gradle instead of maven

I have setup the build.gradle and added tags to the test like so @WithTag("UI:Smoketests"). When I try to run tests with tag UI:Smoketests all the tests get executed.

```
 Command executed: gradle -Ptags="UI:Smoketests"
```

Question: Is there some properties or libraries that need to be aded to build.gradle to execute only test that match a tag?

Comment: `-D` or `-P`? What is your serenity project? JUnit 4 or Cucumber?

Comment: Had to use -D and not -P for serenity BDD Junit framework.

Comment: Is your problem solved or not?

Comment: Yes the issue is resolved thanks!